# How to trigger change event on slate.js when testing with Selenium or Cypress

Tags: selenium, cypress, slate.js

I'm trying to find a way to simulate a "change" event when doing E2E testing (with selenium or cypress) and slate.js

In our UI, when the user clicks on a word, we pop-up a modal (related to that word).  I've been unable to make this happen as I can't get the change event to trigger

Answer (score 3):

The Cypress input commands (e.g. `cy.type()` and `cy.clear()`) work by dispatching `input` and `change` events - in the case of `cy.type()`, one per character. This mimics the behavior of a real browser as a user types on their keyboard and is enough to trigger the behavior of most application JavaScript.

However, Slate relies almost exclusively on the `beforeinput` event (see here https://docs.slatejs.org/concepts/xx-migrating#beforeinput) which is a new browser technology and an event which the Cypress input commands don’t simulate. Hopefully the Cypress team will update their input commands to dispatch the `beforeinput` event, but until they do I’ve created a couple of simple custom commands which will trigger Slate’s input event listeners and make it respond.

```js
// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('getEditor', (selector) => {
    return cy.get(selector)
    .click();
});

Cypress.Commands.add('typeInSlate', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, text) => {
    return cy.wrap(subject)
    .then(subject => {
        subject[0].dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('beforeinput', { inputType: 'insertText', data: text }));
        return subject;
    })
});
    
Cypress.Commands.add('clearInSlate', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
    return cy.wrap(subject)
    .then(subject => {
        subject[0].dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('beforeinput', { inputType: 'deleteHardLineBackward' }))
        return subject;
    })
});

// slateEditor.spec.js
cy.getEditor('[data-testid=slateEditor1] [contenteditable]')
    .typeInSlate('Some input text ');

cy.getEditor('[data-testid=slateEditor2] [contenteditable]')
    .clearInSlate()
    .typeInSlate('http://httpbin.org/status/409');
```

If you need to support other inputTypes, all of the inputTypes supported by Slate are listed [in the source code for editable.tsx](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/16ff44d0566889a843a346215d3fb7621fc0ed8c/packages/slate-react/src/components/editable.tsx#L249)

Comment: Link is missing under `here` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

1) Add a ref to the Editor

```
 <Editor
   ref={this.editor}
 />
```

2) Add a document listener for a custom event

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("Test_SelectWord", this.onTestSelectWord)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("Test_SelectWord", this.onTestSelectWord)
}
```

3) Create a handler that creates a custom select event

```
onTestSelectWord(val: any) {
    let slateEditor = val.detail.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement

    // Events are special, can't use spread or Object.keys
    let selectEvent: any = {}
    for (let key in val) { 
        if (key === 'currentTarget') {
            selectEvent['currentTarget'] = slateEditor
        }
        else if (key === 'type') {
            selectEvent['type'] = "select"
        }
        else {
            selectEvent[key] = val[key] 
        }
    }

    // Make selection
    let selection = window.getSelection();        
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(val.detail);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range)

    // Fire select event
    this.editor.current.onEvent("onSelect", selectEvent)
}
```

4) User the following in your test code:

```
arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cl-token-node"))
text = arr.filter(element => element.children[0].innerText === "*WORD_YOU_ARE_SELECTING*")[0].children[0].children[0]
var event = new CustomEvent("Test_SelectWord", {detail: text})
document.dispatchEvent(event, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress can explicitly trigger events:  https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Syntax

This may work for you:

```
cy.get(#element).trigger("change")
```

Comment: Maybe click event instead. Could you show some code to give an idea of the test logic?